# CodeIgniter dont change my sql table correctly

Tags: php, html, codeigniter

I need to change a string inside my sql, script works without errors, but does nothing. I'm trying to enter ID which row I want to change and then enter condition how to change that row variable. Here is my code.

Controller:

```
public function admin(){
$this->load->model('model_users');
$data2['users'] = $this->model_users->change_condition();
$this->load->view("content_admin", $data2);
}
```

Model:

```
public function change_condition() {
$data = array(
    'order_condition' => $this->input->post('order_condition')
    );
$where = array(
    'ID' => $this->input->post('ID')
        );
$str = $this->db->update_string('users', $data, $where);
}
```

View:

```
<form name="contactform" method="POST" action="<?php echo base_url();?>site/change">
<td valign="top">
ID
</td>
<input  type="text" name="ID" maxlength="20" size="30">
<td valign="top">
Order Condition
</td>
<input  type="text" name="order_condition" maxlength="80" size="30">
<input type="submit" value="Change" name="submit" />
</form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `$this->db->update()` instead of `$this->db->update_string` and pass the `$where` array in `$this->db->where()`. [Example](https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/active_record.html#update):

```
public function change_condition() {
    $data = array(
        'email' => $this->input->post('email')
    );
    $where = array(
        'ID' => $this->input->post('ID')
    );
    $this->db->where($where);
    $str = $this->db->update('users', $data);
    return $str;
}
```

Comment: Code works perfectly, but now I have issue that I have no idea why its happening. So, I use your code to add item inside db, but I need two codes like that so another one I called change_condition2(). So, both codes works, adds items to my DB, but now when I'm changing change_condition() my change_condition2() in the same row become equal to number 0. When Im changing change_condition2(), everything is fine. I have no idea why this happening. I tried mannualy add item inside db via MSQL and everything works fine, so its not DB fault. Maybe you can help with this issue.